# Открытие сформированных документов в MS Office 2007 и более ранней версии

Tags: c#, office, openxml

Использую `OpenXML SDK` для последующего формирования `word` файла на `с#`, полученный сформированный файл имеет расширение `.docx` и без проблем открывается в MS Office 2010 и MS Office 2016, но не открывается в MS Office 2007 (пишет документ был поврежден).

**Может быть кто-то сталкивался?**

Есть идея, что там были разные стандарты OXML. Но хотелось бы получить более развернутый ответ.

Comment: Хорошо, пойдем обратным путем: Если вы создадите документ в самом новом офисе и попытаетесь открыть его в старом, каким будет эффект? Если он успешно откроется, то дело не в стандартах.

Comment: На самом деле разные стандарты. А если поставить file format converters?